# Call same method twice with different parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How to do this below?  Object under test calls ReadAppSetting twice to get two different app settings and defaults a value when it cannot be found.  First call returns null (it means the first moq setup did not work), second time ReadAppSetting returns as expected (moq setup worked).

```
var mock = new Mock<IConfigReader>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.ReadAppSetting("PropA", "George"))
    .Returns("George");
mock.Setup(foo => foo.ReadAppSetting("PropB", "5000"))
    .Returns("5000");
MyClass objectUnderTest = new MyClass(mock.Object);
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean "one of these is ignored/overwritten"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mock object invocation returns `null` then you haven't provide **exactly same** arguments values as used on mock setup. Check how you are invoking config reader in `MyClass`. Possibly you are passing wrong key value, or wrong default value.

BTW if you want config reader to return default values for all invocations, then you can use single setup:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.ReadAppSetting(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns<string, string>((key, defaultValue) => defaultValue);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the mock params and the return value had to match exactly as the code did.

Comment: @O.O nope, you are free to return any value. Thats arguments you are passing to ReadAppSettings during invocation should match arguments you are using to setup mock.